# How to get grouped cumulative duration in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, timedelta

I have the following data:

| id | encounter_key | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 2019-04-14 |
| 1 | 111 | 2019-04-14 |
| 1 | 111 | 2019-07-18 |
| 1 | 122 | 2019-09-02 |
| 2 | 211 | 2019-10-03 |
| 2 | 211 | 2020-10-03 |

I want to find the cumulative duration, grouped by `id` and `encounter_key` to achieve the following:

| id | encounter_key | datetime | cum_duration_days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 2019-04-14 | 0 |
| 1 | 111 | 2019-04-14 | 0 |
| 1 | 111 | 2019-07-18 | 95 |
| 1 | 122 | 2019-09-02 | 0 |
| 2 | 211 | 2019-10-03 | 0 |
| 2 | 211 | 2020-10-03 | 366 |

I've tried `df.groupby(['datetime']).apply( ... )` etc. but nothing seems to work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the expected output has an error. For the second-to-last row, I think it should be 0 not 31

Comment: You're right - have edited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work

```
df['cum_duration_days']=df.groupby(['id','encounter_key'])['datetime'].diff()/ np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
df['cum_duration_days'].fillna(0)
```

But @enke is right, the output desired seems to have an error on the '31' unless you are not showing all the rows for encounter_key=211 /id=2 ...